# Prestashop redirect to the active language

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop

I am working on website with two language (french & english)
as exemple when 'fr' is selected prestshop accept url without language
exmple http://www.atelier-du-couteau.com is same as http://www.atelier-du-couteau.com/fr

I am looking for a way to force Prestashop to **always** use  the right language.

Answer (score -1):

You can edit Prestashop `.htaccess` file.

Add this rule before `# ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment[...]`:

```
### REDIRECT TO /FR IF NO COUNTRY CODE ###
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/([a-z]{2}|admin[^/]+)/.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /fr/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
### /REDIRECT TO /FR IF NO COUNTRY CODE ###
```

Comment: This edit admin address!
How Can redirect urls without admin urls?

Comment: @Memariaan I've edited my answer to exclude admin path.